# How to select more than one database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display data in a browser. I already retrieved data from the databases, but when I call `mysql_select_db`, it accepts only one database. But my data is from a different database.

How will I select them?
if i am writing mysql_select_db it is taking only one data base.for asmany datatabase if i am using mysql_select_db it is accepting but result not displaing in browser. it is showing Maximum execution time of 30 seconds .. if i work on 1 database the results are displaying in browser but when i try to link with more than 1 database in a same conection the problem is comming.

The same problem is also comming when i am trying to link the 2 table in a single database.but if i use single table and no linking with other table than the results are comming

Answer (score 3):

you need to open two different connections

```
$con1 = mysql_connect($server1, $user1, $pass1);
mysql_select_db($con1);

$con2 = mysql_connect($server2, $user2, $pass2);
mysql_select_db($con2);

$query1 = mysql_query($sql1, $con1);
$query2 = mysql_query($sql2, $con2);
```

edit:

if both your databases are accessable with one connection:

say you have two different databases, db1 and db2

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM db1.myTable WHERE something ";
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM db2.myOtherTable WHERE something ";
```

Comment: but all my databases are in one connection. is it will be right to make 2 different connecton?

Comment: oh sorry, then it will be redundant to make two different connections. Then let me edit the response

Comment: these query are fine. i got that.. tell me how to display that in the browser. if i am writing mysql_select_db it is taking only one data base.for asmany datatabase if i am using mysql_select_db it is accepting but result not displaing in browser. it is showing Maximum execution time of 30 seconds .. if i work on 1 database the results are displaying in browser but when i try to link with more than 1 database in a same conection the problem is comming.

Comment: The same problem is also comming when i am trying to link the 2 table in a single database.but if i use single table and no linking with other table than the results are comming.

Answer (score 1):

You can either qualify your queries with the database name `(SELECT * FROM db1.table; SELECT * FROM db2.table)`, or you can run your first query, store its result to a PHP array, call mysql_select_db() and run the second query.

The first approach is somewhat more flexible, in that you can do things like cross-database joins if you want (can't vouch for how well a cross-database join would perform though).

Answer (score 0):

First, get data from the first database and then call `mysql_select_db` for the second database, and then get the values from the second database. You can move to and forth between the databases from where you require the data, just call `mysql_select_db` for that database before calling the php mysql functions.